# Evento change no me funciona

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un programa el cual un usuario le da click a un botón y dicho botón realiza un evento `.click()`, dentro del evento ocurre una acción de mostrar unos input type de selección (select), el cual los muestro de la siguiente manera:

```
let fila = $(".marcaje")

fila.append('<div class="col-12">' + 
                        '<div class="input-group mt-3 mb-3"> ' + 
                            '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                                '<label class="input-group-text">Canal</label>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<select class="custom-select opciones" name="canal" >' +
                                '<option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
                                '<option value="1">Banca Empresa</option>' +
                                '<option value="2">Banca Corporativa</option>' +
                                '<option value="3">Tesoreria</option>' +
                                '<option value="4">CNB</option>' +
                                '<option value="5">Otros Grupos</option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">' + 
                        '<div class="input-group mt-2 mb-2"> ' + 
                            '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                                '<label class="input-group-text">Aliado</label>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<select class="custom-select opciones" name="aliado" >' +
                                '<option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
                                '<option value="1"></option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">' + 
                        '<div class="input-group mt-2 mb-2"> ' + 
                            '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                                '<label class="input-group-text">Gerente</label>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<select class="custom-select opciones" name="gerente">' +
                                '<option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>' +
                                '<option value="1"></option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>' +

                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-4 mt-4 ">' + 
                        '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-dark">Ingresar Clientes</button>' +
                    '</div>');
```

Dichos input type de selección se muestran de la siguiente forma:

[image: Resultado]

Ahora, lo que quiero realizar es un evento `.change()` al momento de que el usuario cambie de opción en cualquiera de uno de los select.

Les añadí una clase (opciones) a cada uno de los select, para así tomar cualquier select que el usuario modifique. El problema es que no toma ningún select que modifico y nunca muestra por consola lo que le pido.

```
$(".opciones").change(function(){
    console.log("Cambio!");
});
```

Comment: El problema es que estás agregando contenido después de que se cargó la página y deberías volver a ejecutar ese último código para asignar la función a los nuevos elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema radica en que tu select se genera de forma dinamica por lo que al cargar la web en principio no existe y es agregado por jquery luego de la carga.

para esto jquery tiene la opcion [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) que lo que haces es re leer un documento a partir de un marcador statico.

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

en tu caso seria.

```
$(".marcaje").on("change",".opciones",function(){
 console.log("Cambio!");
});
```

donde se selecciona el elemento estatico "`.marcaje`" a partir del cual se leera nuevamente el documento, luego se delega el evento a su hijo "`.opciones`" que es ahora quien respondera al evento en cuestion.

Comment: +1, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Te convendria usar la funcion onchange en el select. Por ejemplo

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

Luego en el script haces lo que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando la función onchange en el html

```
<select id="select" name ="select" onchange="selectFunction()">
```

Aquí cuando hagas un cambio en el select este ejecutará la función selectFunction()

Comment: Pero esto ya aparece en una respuesta existente desde 2022!